# asihttprequest download only if not already stored

Tags: ios, file, if-statement, download, asihttprequest

I am donwloading and retrieving files with `ASIHTTPRequest`. It already works, but now I am trying to break the download, when it is already stored. I can't figure out, how to implement this problem. I would like to solve it with an if-clause: if the file is not cached, download it else break. Would you mind to help me writing a proper Objective-C code? I have the file path, if I need it so compare or look after that file.

Thanks in advance!

pseudo code :

```
        -(IBAction) download : (id) sender {
    if (data1.pdf) { 
       // the download algorithm
    }
    else 
       break;
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to the question; but the ASIHTTPRequest project is no longer under development and the developer [suggested](http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D) alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how you can check if a file is stored in the documents directory of your device, then you can use:

```
NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* file = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.pdf"];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:file]) {
   ...
```

Comment: ah thanks! I loaded it in the cachesdirectory, but that should be similar, i will try it :)